# More systems not booting after meldown patch?

Tags: boot, updates, security

I have to Dell Poweredge 730 systems running 14.04 LTS that will not boot after a security update last night (probably for meltdown). This article on softpedia helped me:
http://news.softpedia.com/news/canonical-fixes-ubuntu-16-04-lts-regression-causing-boot-failure-on-some-pcs-519320.shtml
Are more people here affected by this? And why me?

Regards,
Nico

Comment: We do not support question that boil down to a yes/no. What do you expect? 2 answers, 1 yes, 1 no and people upvote the one they ended up with? The 2nd question is impossible to answer by us. Questions need to target a specific problem we can address. Please provide information about errors, notices etc you get from logs onscreen or from an emergency boot.

Comment: Listing all the machines and OS version combinations affected by the `kernel panic` bug introduced when trying to implement the Meltdown security hole fix would be too long. As such your question is too broad IMO.

Comment: "Are more people here affected by this?" you already answered this question with the link you referenced , the title alone answers this question. The second question "why me?" you are just luck enough to have a CPU affected by a rapidly changing situation where kernel developers at Canonical and beyond are trying to fix a problem ASAP. I am sure it will all settle down in a few days or weeks and moving forward newer patches will be better.